# Looking for an example of finite acyclic quiver path algebra with a simple module of infinite projective dimension

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quiver

I am looking for an example of finite acyclic quiver path algebra with a simple module of infinite projective dimension.

I have considered the following. Consider quiver $1\to 2\to 3\to 4$. Form path algebra $kQ$ over algebraic closed field $k$. After a few line computation, it seems that all simple modules have finite projective dimension. So I have to conclude that all finitely generated modules must have finite projective dimension.(As any f.g module $M\supset MJac(KQ)\supset MJac(KQ)^2\supset\dots 0$  gives a filtration of simples and those filtration pastes the resolution where $Jac(KQ)$ denotes Jacobson radical, any f.g. $M$ has finite projective resolution.) And the computed resolution length for simples is bounded by $4$.

$\textbf{Q1:}$ Is it true that simple modules' projective dimension bounded by $n$ for type $A_n$? Furthermore, if that is the case, I would deduce every f.g. module $M$ say $dim_k(M)=l$, has projective dimension at most $ln$.

$\textbf{Q2:}$ How can I find a simple module of a finite acyclic quiver path algebra with infinite projective dimension?

Comment: I am confused. Acyclic path algebras are hereditary, so every module has projective dimension $\leq 1$. What am I missing?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer You are right. So I guess I do not know that conclusion beforehand. The only way to get infinite projective dimension is by cyclic case.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Is there a finitely generated module $M$ over path algebra $R$ with cycles s.t. $[M]$ in $K_0(R)$ does not contain the simple module with infinite projective dimension? or is there characterization of finitely generated modules of infinite dimensions over artinian $k-$algebra?